# Изменить цвет элементов radiobutton android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, radiobutton

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]у меня есть alertdialog, в котором я создаю radiogroup, как я могу поменять цвет текста и цвет самих radiobutton?

```
private fun showDialog(){
    lateinit var dialog:AlertDialog
    var them_alert=0
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    var text=TextView(baseContext)
    text.setText("Choose theme")
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
    text.setPadding(0,40,0,0)
    text.setTextSize(25F)
    if (them==1){
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)

    }
    else{
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        text.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.pole))

    }
    var checked=1
    builder.setCustomTitle(text)
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes){
        dialog, which->
        if (them_alert==1){
            Dark()
        }
        else if (them_alert==2){
            Light()
        }
    }
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel){
        dialog, which->
    }
    if (them==1){
        checked=1
    }
    else{
        checked=0
    }
    val array= arrayOf("Dark", "Light")
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(array,checked,{_,which->
        val color = array[which]
        if (color =="Dark"){
            them_alert=1 //dark
        }
        if (color =="Light"){
            them_alert=2 //light
        }
    })
    dialog = builder.create()
    if(them==1){
        dialog.getWindow()!!.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.white)
        //dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    }
    else{
        dialog.getWindow()!!.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.pole)
    }
    dialog.show()
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для изменения цвета кнопки вам нужно будет создавать свои использовать:

```
android:buttonTint="@color/your_color"
```

так он выглядит в xml разметке вашей активности/фрагмента:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:checked="true"
    android:buttonTint="@color/your_color"/>
```

и дальше цвет в colors.xml

```
<color name="your_color">#e75748</color>
```

в коде это делается так программно:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21)
{

    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{

                    new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, //disabled
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
            },
            new int[] {

                    Color.BLACK //disabled
                    ,Color.BLUE //enabled

            }
        );                       


    radio.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);//set the color tint list
    radio.invalidate(); //could not be necessary
}
```

можно так же создать стиль для текста кнопки:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#0f0"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:color="#00f"/>
</selector>
```

и подключить его к кнопке:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/radiobuttonstate"/>
```

оба способа вполне рабочие, самый простой это `buttonTint`. Для изменения цвета текста используйте textColor в xml разметке. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945134/android-radiobutton-textcolor-selector) есть вопрос по вашей тематике и [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button) еще один.